# transparent background not exporting AE6

Tags: video, export, html5-video, alpha, after-effects

Checked loads of tutorials and forums and I do not find my solution. I did the following:

-Create composition

-Click on toggle composition
-Worked on material, the background has the classic alpha layout. The same as if the background is transparent with Photoshop.

-Added composition to render queue

-Settings: Quicktime + RGB+Alpha + millions of colors+ + premultiplied + animation as output

-Render

When I open the animation I still get the original gray background the project had.

I already tried using PNG as output, FLV with transparent background, straight instead of premultiplied...

My goal is to use this animation with the video tag and use [videoforeverybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) method.

Answer (score 0):

For any person who is curious to know. At this moment there isn't compatibility to display a animation video which can work with transparency on the web. I found some fixes but there are not perfect. Hereby I leave the link:

https://github.com/m90/jquery-seeThru

I also checked that on Google Canary they are beginning to work themselves through this problem and beginning to implement a new techonlogy for video which works with green chrome which is really interesting:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/07/Alpha-transparency-in-Chrome-video

Hope you enjoy!